# The counter tcbbreakpart blocks at 2 when adding tcolorbox tabs

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters, tcolorbox

A very long `tcolorbox` can be broken into many boxes. "The parts of the break sequence are numbered by the counter tcbbreakpart." (p. 363 of manual 4.11)

Now, let's add a side tab to every page, made either with a `tcolorbox` or with TiKZ.

**tcbbreakpart** works well when the tab is made with TiKZ.

**tcbbreakpart** stops at 2 when the right tab is a tcolorbox.

Is there a way to unblock the counter `tcbbreakpart` ?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[margin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}



% Tabs with TColorBox  

\newcommand{\TcolorBoxTab}[1]{
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,size=normal,center upper,fontupper={\bfseries\huge\scshape},arc=3mm,width=22cm,
colback={#1!20}, rounded corners=north, sharp corners=south, bottomrule=0mm]
\underline{tcbbreakpart} stops at 2 when the tab is a tcolorbox.\\ Here \underline{tcbbreakpart} = \arabic{tcbbreakpart}
\end{tcolorbox}
}

\newcommand{\TColorBoxRightTabs}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node (RightTab1) [above,xshift=0mm,rotate=90] at 
(current page.east){\TcolorBoxTab{red}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


% Tabs with TiKz

\tikzset{RightTabStyle/.style={align=center,
text=blue!80!black,font=\scshape\bfseries\huge,
text width=23cm, text height=1cm, text depth=1.5cm,
inner sep=0pt,thick,rectangle,rounded corners=5pt,rotate=0,
draw=blue,fill=pink!50}}  %


\newcommand{\TikzRightTabs}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node (RightTab1) [
RightTabStyle,
above,xshift=0mm,rotate=90] at 
(current page.east) {
\underline{tcbbreakpart} works well when the tab is made with TiKZ.\\ Here \underline{tcbbreakpart} = \arabic{tcbbreakpart}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


%-->>> Tabs made with TColorBox block the counter of broken boxes.<<--
\AddToShipoutPicture{
%\TikzRightTabs% tcbbreakpart works well
\TColorBoxRightTabs% blocks tcbbreakpart at #2
}



\begin{document}

% Example modified from  tcolorbox-example.tex (2017-09-14) by Prof. Dr. Dr. Thomas F. Sturm

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,breakable,pad at break*=1mm,
colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,title={Example modified from  tcolorbox-example.tex (2017-09-14) by Prof. Dr. Dr. Thomas F. Sturm},
fonttitle=\huge\bfseries,
title after break={\huge\bfseries
\underline{tcbbreakpart} is \arabic{tcbbreakpart}},
watermark color=yellow,watermark text=\Roman{tcbbreakpart}]
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I understand that `tcbbreakpart` is defined for every particular tcolorbox, therefore the variable used in sidebars is different from the one used in main box. while as `tikz` version doesn't use a new tcolorbox, the counter is the one defined by the main tcolorbox.

Comment: After looking a little bit inside `tcolorbox` code, I think my previous comment was wrong. Now I think that there exists only one common `tcbbreakpart` counter, and this is fixed to value 1 on every new box (see line 1673 in tcolorbox.sty) , therefore when you draw the side box after every break part, the counter is changed to 1 and as the break part uses the same counter, it is just increased in one unit to show  2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ignasi wrote: The `tcbbreakpart` counter is 'unique' and not a `per-box` counter entity, so resetting occurs in every side tab box -- a possible solution is to store the counter value, but this is quite tricky.

I've used (well, my ;-) package `xassoccnt` to provide a stored counter that is stepped each time the `tcbbreakpart` counter is increased an restore the value of `tcbbreakpart` after each side tab box.

I also shifted the `tab box` into an underlay of the `pagebox`, in order to get rid of the asynchronous ship out.

Side note: In most cases it is better to define specialized boxes instead of using `\begin{tcolorbox}...\end{tcolorbox}` all the while.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[margin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\newcounter{pagebox}

\newcounter{tcbbreakpartstored}[pagebox]

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{tcbbreakpart}{tcbbreakpartstored}

% Tabs with tcolorbox  




\newtcolorbox{tabbox}[2][]{%
    size=normal,
    center upper,
    fontupper={\bfseries\huge\scshape},
    arc=3mm,
    width=22cm,
    colback={#2!20},
    rounded corners=north, 
    sharp corners=south, 
    bottomrule=0mm,
    before={\setcounter{tcbbreakpart}{\value{tcbbreakpartstored}+1}}% Use the stored value  
}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=pagebox]{pagebox}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  remember,
  breakable,
  pad at break*=1mm,
  colback=blue!5!white,
  colframe=blue!75!black,
  title={Example modified from  tcolorbox-example.tex (2017-09-14) by Prof. Dr. Dr. Thomas F. Sturm},
  fonttitle=\huge\bfseries,
  title after break={\huge\bfseries\underline{tcbbreakpart} is \arabic{tcbbreakpart}},
  underlay broken={%
    \node (RightTab1) [above,xshift=0mm,rotate=90] at 
    (current page.east){\TcolorBoxTab{red}};
    },
  watermark color=yellow,
  watermark text=\Roman{tcbbreakpart},
  #1,
}



\newcommand{\TcolorBoxTab}[1]{%
  \begin{tabbox}{#1}
    \underline{tcbbreakpart} continues when the tab is a tcolorbox.\\ Here \underline{tcbbreakpart} = \arabic{tcbbreakpart}.
  \end{tabbox}
}


\newcommand{\TColorBoxRightTabs}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \node (RightTab1) [above,xshift=0mm,rotate=90] at 
    (current page.east){\TcolorBoxTab{red}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}


% Tabs with TiKz

\tikzset{RightTabStyle/.style={
    align=center,
    text=blue!80!black,
    font=\scshape\bfseries\huge,
    text width=23cm, 
    text height=1cm, 
    text depth=1.5cm,
    inner sep=0pt,
    thick,
    rectangle,
    rounded corners=5pt,
    rotate=0,
    draw=blue,
    fill=pink!50}
}  %


\newcommand{\TikzRightTabs}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \node (RightTab1) [
    RightTabStyle,
    above,xshift=0mm,rotate=90] at 
    (current page.east) {
      \underline{tcbbreakpart} works well when the tab is made with TiKZ.\\ Here \underline{tcbbreakpart} = \arabic{tcbbreakpart}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}


%-->>> Tabs made with TColorBox block the counter of broken boxes.<<--
\AddToShipoutPicture{
  % \TikzRightTabs% tcbbreakpart works well
%  \TColorBoxRightTabs% blocks tcbbreakpart at #2
}



\begin{document}

% Example modified from  tcolorbox-example.tex (2017-09-14) by Prof. Dr. Dr. Thomas F. Sturm

\begin{pagebox}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{pagebox}

% Another pagebox
\begin{pagebox}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{pagebox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am grateful that you introduced me to the very useful packages refcount (in your earlier answer) and xassoccnt. I must say that your documentation for xassoccnt is very agreeable to search into and that its visual is clear and beautiful.

Comment: @SDrolet: Thanks for the compliments. The `xassoccnt` manual is written with `tcolorbox` 'documentation' library. `refcount` is from Heiko Oberdiek, however.